# Shell script to update last character of the filename

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have files in directories and sub directories, the filename should be changed such that, the last character should be replaced to a number or a character depending upon arguments provided. I could do it for numbers but not happening for a character.

For eg. if File names are `20170504ABCDXXXYYY6.xml` or  `20170504CFLFXXXYYY6.cfl.bz2`.

If I write the command `./updateLastCharacter 5`, file names should be `20170504ABCDXXXYYY5.xml` or `20170504CFLFXXXYYY5.cfl.bz2`.

If the command is `./updateLastCharacter A`, file names should be `20170504ABCDXXXYYYA.xml` or `20170504CFLFXXXYYYA.cfl.bz2`.

I'm new to shell scripting. I tried a lot for making it happen but what I could do is :

```
find $directory -exec rename "s/[0-9].xml/$newNumber.xml/;s/[0-9].cfl/$newRevisionNumber.cfl/" {} ";"
```

This works fine for number but I'm looking for how can I do it for a character with single line command.

Comment: characters as in you want to search for A-Z and a-z, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution with `rename` ( perl function )

`find . | rename -n -v 's/[A-Za-z0-9](?=\.)/5/'`

`-n` means no action
`-v` means verbose to the screen

[image]

---

And you can use [`renrem`](https://github.com/k-five/renrem) program utility **directly** that is more powerful than rename in Perl.
*I wrote that program to myself because I needed a lot to rename or remove files.*

[image]